# Collation conflict when using NULLIF

Tags: sql-server, collation

Here is the simplified query that shows up the error

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between
>   "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal
>   to operation.

```
SELECT top 2 NULLIF(CONCAT(A.Col_1, A.Col_2),'') from [server].[db].[dbo].[Table_1] as A
```

I have tried searching for easy solution for the error and it turned up that everybody is talking about using specific or default Collation in the where clause. But as I don't have any where clause how can I fix it.

Note: Without using `NULLIF` it works fine

Note: I cannot change Collation of any of the two DB servers I am working on.

Well with this change the query is now executing. Not sure if this is the best way though.

```
SELECT top 2 NULLIF(CONCAT(A.oem1105_strategicoverview, A.oem1105_bigbetstrategies),'' COLLATE database_default)
from [hyd2oemcrmdev15].[OEM_CRM_MSCRM].[dbo].[Account] as A ORDER BY A.AccountId
```

Comment: The N'' did not solve it. The reason of having different collation is probably  that I have to execute SQL query to another server from a different server

Comment: `NULLIF` must compare its two arguments  so collation matters. The [COLLATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx)  clause isn't restricted to `WHERE` statements, it can be used at the query level or in functions as well. Also, check *why* this happened. Why are Windows and SQL Server Latin1 codepages mixed? You should be using the Windows collation (Latin1_General_CI_AS) throughout. SQL Server collations exist only for compatibility purposes.

Comment: You can apply `COLLATE` to function arguments. Try `NULLIF(CONCAT(A.Col_1, A.Col_2) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS ,''))` or `NULLIF(CONCAT(A.Col_1, A.Col_2),''  COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS))`